# Написать sqrt через ряды Тейлора с++

Tags: c++

Добрый день! 
Помогите, пожалуйста реализовать функцию квадратного корня из числа через ряд Тейлора на с++: 
Вот некоторые похожие рабочие функции

```
    double f_sin(double var)
{
    double q,sum=0;
    int n;
    q=var;
    for(n=1;n <= 100;n++){///синус через ряды
    sum+=q;
    q*=(-1)*var*var/(2*n)/(2*n+1);
}
return sum;
}

double f_cos(double var)
{
double q,sum=1;
int n;
q=var;
q*=(-1)*var/2;
sum+=q;
for(n=2;n <= 100;n++){///косинус через ряды тейлора
    q*=(-1)*var*var/(2*n)/(2*n-1);
    sum+=q;
}
return sum;
}

double f_sqrt(double var)
{
/*var--;
double q=-1, sum=1;
for(int n=1; n<=100; n++){
    q*=(-1)*var/2; /// не работает
    sum+=q;
}*/
return sum;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Помочь реализовать или написать с нуля? Чтобы помочь, надо видеть хоть какие-то ваши наработки

Comment: @СашаБоричевский вот))

Comment: @user273587 А чем ваш закоментированный код не работает?

Comment: @Arty OneSoul нет, помогите исправить пожалуйста

Comment: @user273587 Судя по виду ряда я предполагаю что он работает только для малых `x` (по модулю меньше 1), для больших он думаю будет неограниченно расти, не будет сходиться, т.к. там в числителях быстро растущие степени. Нужно попробовать другой ряд если такой существует.

Comment: @user273587 Кстати ваш вариант не работает в частности изза того что вы считаете в знаменателе степени двойки, а там более сложное выражение со степенью четвёрки и факториалом, нужно поменять формулу расчёта.

Comment: @ArtyOneSoul, вероятно, знаменатель там растёт гораздо быстрее)

Answer (score 1):

Сделал исправления в f_sqrt функцию закоментированную, код без рекурсии, только этот ряд работает для `x` из `[0,2]`, для больших значений ряд расходится. Ошибка у автора была в том, что он полагал что в знаменателе просто степени двойки, а там значительно более сложное выражение и в числителе и знаменателе. Вот что получилось, [можно запустить онлайн](https://repl.it/OBgf/0):

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double f_sqrt(double var)
{
    var -= 1;
    double q = 1, sum = 1;
    for(int n=1; n <= 100; n++){
        q *= (-1.0) * (2 * n - 1) * 2 * n * var / (n * n * 4);
        sum += q / (1.0 - 2 * n);
    }
    return sum;
}

int main() {
    double x = 1.5;
    cout << f_sqrt(x) << endl;
    cout << sqrt(x) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ну вот просто интересно, почему? например, `* 2 * n * var / (n * n * 4)`, а не `var/(2*n)`? :)

Comment: @Harry Чтобы просто в точности соответствовать формуле, конечно, форумулу можно упростить.

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте такой вариант может. но и ваш вроде как должен работать, непонятно почему не срабатывает

```
double f_sqrt(double var, float eps) {
    //eps - точность, при достижении которой останавливаемся
    double sum = 0, tmp = 0;
    int n = 0;
    while(tmp > eps) {
       tmp = (pow(-1, n) * fact(2 * n))/((1 - 2 * n) * pow(fact(n), 2) * pow(4, n)) * pow(var, n);
       sum += tmp;
       n++;
    }
    return sum;
}

int fact(int n)
{
if(N < 0)
    return 0;
if (N == 0)
    return 1; 
else
    return N * fact(N - 1);
}
```

Comment: Красиво поиздевались :)

Comment: @Harry зато все в соответствии с формулой) да и считать сумму бесконечного ряда, ограничивая итерации конкретным числом - не меньшее извращение)

Comment: Да нет, я не об ограничении знакопеременного ряда - тут все нормально... я о применении `fact` (еще и рекурсивного) и `pow`

Comment: @Harry, что-то сомневаюсь я, что тут был сарказм))

Comment: @vp_arth зря сомневаетесь. Настроение хорошее просто, хочется веселья)

Comment: @Harry, рекурсия — наше всё, особенно хвостовая. И вообще, памяти у компьютеров нынче много, нечего экономить на спичках. Пусть машинное слово будет широким как русская душа, а стек — глубоким как Марианская впадина.